# Submit a spark application from Windows to a Linux cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Master and Worker running on a remote Ubuntu Linux machine.

I'm trying to run the [JavaDirectKafkaWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java) example.
But when I submit from my Windows machine to the Linux cluster I get

> C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.123.45.67:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.company.spark.app.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount "C:/Dev/spark-app/target/spark-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" kafka-server:9092 topic1
>
> Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
>   Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   16/02/11 11:53:20 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://10.123.45.67:6066.
>   16/02/11 11:53:21 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submission successfully created as driver-20160211115129-0009. Polling submission state...
>   16/02/11 11:53:21 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20160211115129-0009 in spark://10.123.45.67:6066.
>   16/02/11 11:53:21 INFO RestSubmissionClient: State of driver driver-20160211115129-0009 is now ERROR.
>   16/02/11 11:53:21 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Driver is running on worker worker-20160211111114-172.18.0.8-59825 at 172.18.0.8:59825.
>   16/02/11 11:53:21 ERROR RestSubmissionClient: Exception from the cluster:
>   java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
>           org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
>           org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
>           org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
>           org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
>           org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
>           org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
>           org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1650)
>           org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:597)
>           org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:394)
>           org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$DriverRunner$$downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:150)
>           org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:79)
>   16/02/11 11:53:21 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Server responded with
>       CreateSubmissionResponse:
>       {
>       "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
>       "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160211115129-0009",
>         "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.0",
>         "submissionId" : "driver-20160211115129-0009",
>         "success" : true
>       }

Comment: Does it work when running locally?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Spark is taking C: as the schema. Try changing to

```
C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.123.45.67:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.company.spark.app.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount "file:///C:/Dev/spark-app/target/spark-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" kafka-server:9092 topic1
```

By adding `file:///` to the file path you are telling Spark that the schema is `file`, so it will not get confused and use `C` as the schema. Jars submitted to spark using file should get [hosted by spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) so the cluster can see them.

Comment: tried `file:///` that but submit complains `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:/Dev/spark-app/target/spark-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (No such file or directory)` This file does exist however?
Thought the slash before the `C:/` was causing this so removed one slash from `file://` but it doesn't like that either `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component`

Comment: It may be worth putting a quick application together and seeing what `new File("C:/Dev/spark-app/target/spark-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar").toURI()` returns as I don't see anything wrong with the answer I posted, but I don't currently have access to a windows box to test it.

Answer (score 0):

The application jar file you input at the submit command use the windows location, but according for the spark official document:

> application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes.

So the file must be exist or accessible from each of the cluster member, if use the local file system, you must make sure the file exist at very node.

At my local environment, I use the *file:///opt/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.1.jar*, it can pass the test.